# JavaScript Prototype Property Mirror Another Property

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, prototype, internet-explorer-10

We have a bunch of forms on our Intranet coded for IE9 that contain code similar to this:

```
var dept = req.responseXML.selectNodes("//Dept")[0].text;
```

We just upgraded all of our PCs to IE10 and selectNodes is now obsolete and has been replaced with querySelectorAll, so the corrected bit of code would be:

```
var dept = req.responseXML.querySelectorAll("Dept")[0].textContent;
```

All these forms use a shared JS file for sending requests out so I thought if I could define some prototype functions/properties I could fix this incompatibility without touching every form. I made some progress and was able to map selectNodes to querySelectorAll using:

```
Document.prototype.selectNodes = function(param) {
    return this.querySelectorAll(param.replace("//", ""));
}
```

However I am now running into issues mapping text to textContent.  The following doesn't seem to work:

```
Element.prototype.text = function() {
    return this.textContent;
};
```

If anyone has any adivce I would greatly appreciate it, I really don't want to track all these forms down. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It really seems that you ought to fix your code rather than hack the DOM methods in order to avoid fixing your code.  Imagine how this builds up over time and your code gets further and further away from programming to a standard DOM and then at some point, you'll probably even have a name collision with something that changes in a browser.

If you wanted to hack the code so that `elem.text` returns `elem.textContent`, then because these are properties references, not function calls you need to use a getter like this:

```
Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement.prototype, "text", {
    get: function() {
        return this.textContent || this.innerText;
    },
    set: function(txt) {
        if (this.textContent) {
            this.textContent = txt;
        } else {
            this.innerText = txt;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This was the solution! Your advice is correct, however my environment requires the old IE9 code to still function in IE10.

Comment: @JaredFeldman - The better way to handle compatibility for older browsers is to change your code to use the newer interface (to work in newer browsers) and then add a polyfill for older browsers.  This keeps your code standard, prevents conflicts in the future because you're only using standard properties in your code and makes your code a lot easier to understand for those who come after you in the future (because it uses known standards).  You are doing the opposite - coding to an old proprietary interface and trying to make the new browser still implement that.